# Irate not working on any screen but the first screen.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I seem to have this problem with irate where it only works on the very first screen and not the other screens. Any tips on what I may be doing wrong?

```
 [iRate sharedInstance].applicationBundleID = @"MOOO";
[iRate sharedInstance].onlyPromptIfLatestVersion = NO;

[iRate sharedInstance].previewMode =YES;
```

It is giving me this message "iRate did not prompt for rating because the app was first used less than 10 days ago
"
but as soon as I implement that code for the first screen it shows irate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the normal use for iRate will check every time the user opens the app to see if it has been at least 10 days since they first got the app, if it has not been at least 10 days, it will not ask them to rate it.  You have previewMode = YES; which i'm assuming is used for the developer to make sure that iRate is implemented properly and will show when the application launches, not waiting 10 days.  iRate is doing these checks when the application launches and so if it is going to pop up, it will pop up when the first screen is shown.

Comment: cool, also by any chance is there a way to change the default 10 days?

Comment: same place where you do that other stuff do this too: [iRate sharedInstance].daysUntilPrompt = 5; just put whatever number you want instead of 5. Don't forget to accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: It wasn't helpful enough sorry.... just kidding.Also one last question, does it appear anywhere else besides launch?Because all I seem to get is launch.

Comment: Just on launch, it only checks once there and does what it needs to do there.  It is good practice to ask a user to rate your app after a certain period of time, like 5-10 days since you want to allow them the chance to use the app first.  Asking a user to rate an app immediately or asking a user to rate an app repeatedly during one session might cause low app ratings by annoyed users.